# Calculate subgraph density distribution?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(E,V)$ be an undirected graph, and let $S=(E_S,V_S)$ be a subgraph of $G$.

Also let the density of $S$ to be defined as $d(S)=\frac{|E_S|}{|V_S|}$.

What is the probability distribution of $d(S)$ of all subgraphs with $k$ edges ($k=|E_S|$)?

I am particularly interested in a sort of shortcut for the calculation of this distribution as enumerating all subgraphs becomes computationally very expensive.

Comment: How are you selecting the graph?

Comment: graph $G$ or $S$?

Comment: Do you have any assumptions on $G$? With no assumptions it seems like it would be hard to say much. A Monte-Carlo approach could give a reasonable way of estimating the probability.

Comment: The graph $G$ is derived from a metabolic map. It is an undirected graph, other than that it can be pretty much any kind of graph...

Comment: What sort of sizes are you talking about? How are the graphs being represented? Are you generating such subgraphs by simply selecting random subsets of $k$ edges with uniform probability?

Comment: Another question -- does your notion of subgraph admit vertices of degree 0, or are you assuming that all vertices in the subgraph are incident to one of the $k$ edges?

Comment: $|E| \approx 300$ and $|V| \approx 1000$, and $k \approx 100$. Regarding the subgraph generation, given that, indeed, enumerating all of them is not practical I would like a method that randomly selects subgraphs of $k$ edges uniformly from graph $G$.

Comment: All vertices in the subgraph are incident to one of the $k$ edges indeed.

Comment: I think what most accurately describes what I need to do is bootstrapping $k$ edges of graph $G$ and determine the graph density on those subgraphs defined by those sampled $k$ edges. The idea is to have a null distribution of the statistic graph density so that I can later determine how rare a specific subgraph is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easy enough to estimate these probabilities in almost any programming language. Here is one in R (when I have time later today I'll do it in Python as well to confirm the numbers):

```
# In the following functions a graph/subgraph is represented as
# a matrix in which edges are stored in rows
# it is assumed that no edge is stored twice

randSubgraph <- function(graph,k){
  graph[sample(1:nrow(graph),k),]
}

subgraphDensity <- function(edges){
  nrow(edges)/length(unique(as.vector(edges)))
}

# For testing purposes:

completeGraph <- function(n){
  G <- expand.grid(1:(n-1),2:n)
  G <- as.matrix(G[G[,1]<G[,2],])
  dimnames(G) <- NULL
  G
}

G <- completeGraph(500)
subGraphDensities <- replicate(1000,subgraphDensity(randSubgraph(G,100)))
print(mean(subGraphDensities))
hist(subGraphDensities)
```

The program generates 1000 100-edge random subgraphs of the complete graph on 500 vertices, calculates the subgraph densities of them, and returns the mean of them, as well as making a histogram. I've run it several times an gotten consistent results (which suggests that the sample size of 1000 is more than enough). The last time I ran it I got a mean density of 0.605863, with the flowing histogram:

[image]

**On Edit**: Here is a simple Python version, which represents graphs as simply a list of 2-element sets:

```
def estimateDensity(G,k,n = 1000):
    total = 0
    for i in range(n):
        S = random.sample(G,k)
        total += k/len(set.union(*S))
    return total/n

def completeGraph(n):
    return [{i,j} for i in range(1,n) for j in range(i+1,n+1)]
```

For example,

```
>>> estimateDensity(completeGraph(500),100)

0.6056279747464909
```

which meshes with the R output.